# Парсинг страницы в одноклассниках

Tags: парсер, curl, php-curl, odnoklassniki-api, одноклассники

Мне нужно осуществить поиск по группам в одноклассниках с помощью скрипта. И именно для групп такого метода нет в API одноклассников (он заявлен, но, увы, не работает). Думаю получить список групп парсингом такой страницы:

[https://ok.ru/search?st.query=сосиска&st.mode=Groups](https://ok.ru/search?st.query=%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0&st.mode=Groups)

Но у меня не получается авторизоваться. Возможно ли через access token как-то это сделать?